# How to use pip with different python versions?

Tags: python, pip

I have python 3.7.4 and python 3.6.4 on my machine since that some packages don't work on 3.7.4 version

How to use pip with the 3.6.4 version ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+different+python+versions

Answer (score -1):

You can use a python version management program to switch between several Python versions for your projects.

I recommend, `pyenv` but you can also use `pipenv` wich is also a package management utility.

Pyenv : https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv
Pipenv : https://github.com/pypa/pipenv

Comment: thank u , it is resolved